# How to use default template parameters in partial template specialization with variadic templates and multiple parameter packs

Tags: c++, templates, specialization, variadic, default-parameters

I have a problem with the specialization of a template class using two different kinds of variadic parameter packs. In Detail, we have a "variadic type" like

```
template< typename... Arguments > 
struct VariadicType{};
```

The template class using a single type and two different variadic parameter packs is

```
template< typename Type , class , class > 
struct foo{};
```

We specialize this template for gaining access to the two different parameter packs as follows:

```
template<  typename Type ,
           template< class... > class FirstPack_Container  , class... First  ,
           template< class... > class SecondPack_Container , class... Second      >
struct foo< Type , FirstPack_Container< First... > , SecondPack_Container< Second... > > {
     //
     foo(First... first , Second... second){
          std::cout << "sizeof...(first)  = " << sizeof...(first)  << std::endl;
          std::cout << "sizeof...(second) = " << sizeof...(second) << std::endl;
     }
};
```

For instantiation of an object of type foo we have to typedef two different VariadicType's:

```
typedef VariadicType<int,float,double> FirstPack;
typedef VariadicType<double,std::string> SecondPack;
```

With this types in hand we may write

```
foo<int,FirstPack,SecondPack> my_foo_object(1,2.,3.,4.,"bla");
```

But if you want to use the foo-structure with only one variadic parameter Pack, we have to write:

```
typedef VariadicType<> EmptyType;
foo<int,FirstPack,EmptyType> my_bar_object(1,2.,3.);
```

Therefore the question arises, if there is a possibility or a workaraound to give the specialized foo structure an EmptyType as default template parameter for SecondPack_Container. Alternatively, is it possible to specialize foo again for only one variadic Parameter Pack and if yes, how?

For the sake of simplicity, here is a fully working minimal cpp-File for compilation (using gcc 4.7):

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

// Compile with Debug-Information : g++ -o X.bin -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 -g X.cpp
// Holder-Class for variadic Arguments
template< typename... Arguments >
struct VariadicType{};

// Template Class for usage of two different variadic Parameter-Packs
template< typename Type , class , class > 
struct foo{};

// Specialization of foo for direct Access of the two different variadic Parameter-Packs
template<      typename Type ,
               template< class... > class FirstPack_Container  , class... First  ,
               template< class... > class SecondPack_Container , class... Second      >
struct foo< Type , FirstPack_Container< First... > , SecondPack_Container< Second... > > {
     //
     foo(First... first , Second... second){
         std::cout << "sizeof...(first)  = " << sizeof...(first)  << std::endl;
         std::cout << "sizeof...(second) = " << sizeof...(second) << std::endl;
     }
};

int main(){
     // Definition of "variadic Pack Types" for usage in foo:
     typedef VariadicType<int,float,double> FirstPack;
     typedef VariadicType<double,std::string> SecondPack;
     //
     // Instantiation of foo-Object with two Parameter-Packs:
     foo<int,FirstPack,SecondPack> my_foo_object(1,2.,3.,4.,"bla");
     //
     // But now: the second parameter Pack has to be empty.
     // A "variadic empty Type":
     typedef VariadicType<> EmptyType;
     // Instantiation of a foo-Object with only FirstPack:
     foo<int,FirstPack,EmptyType> my_bar_object(1,2.,3.);

     return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, but my questions are not very concise! The specialization of struct foo for only one variadic parameter pack is obvious and simple. I want to avoid to plant the whole structure foo a further time for specialization. So I did the following simple trick: I created a variadic TemplateTypeFactory as follows:

```
typedef VariadicType<> EmptyType;

template<typename Type,class X1,class X2=EmptyType>
struct TemplateTypeFactory{};

template<  typename ReturnType,
           template<class...> class FirstType  , class... first  ,
           template<class...> class SecondType , class... second >
struct TemplateTypeFactory<ReturnType,FirstType<first...>,SecondType<second...>>{
      typedef foo<ReturnType,VariadicType<first...>,VariadicType<second...>> Type;
};

template<  typename ReturnType,
           template<class...> class FirstType  , class... first     >
struct TemplateTypeFactory<ReturnType,FirstType<first...>,Empty_Type>{
      typedef foo<ReturnType,VariadicType<first...>,Empty_Type> Type;
};
```

**NOTE:** In the Deklaration of TemplateFactory I used EmptType as Default-Parameter for the second template type X2.

To use this TemplateType Factory we may write:

```
typedef TemplateTypeFactory<int,FirstPack,SecondPack> foo_type_3;
foo_type_2::Type foo_3(1,2.,3.,4.,"bla");

typedef TemplateTypeFactory<int,FirstPack> foo_type_4;
foo_type_4::Type foo_4(1,2.,3.);
```

Therefore the Question is answered by myself!

Comment: why didn't you add `C++` tag?? you would get answer very quickly

Comment: This is a very good question! Simply, I forgot this! Thanks for this comment. I will correct...

Comment: now it's a little too late to draw attention, if you still need answer then delete this one and ask a new one